# Javascript Method Chaining in NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

When you chain a method in javascript, does it get called on the initial object? Or the return object of the previous method?

I am asking this because in Node I am chaining `.listen()`.

**It works:**

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
   });
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8088);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

It doesn't work when `listen()` is called after `createServer`:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
   });
   response.end('Hello World\n');
})

http.listen(8088);
```

It says that `listen()` is not function. Why does it work when I chain it then?

Comment: It gets called on the return value

Answer (score 2):

Because http is the module which is different from the instance of `http.Server` created by createServer.  See documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) and try `console.log()` ing the variables to see what functions and properties are defined on them.

Answer (score 0):

Fluent interfaces work by returning the same object you called on (by ending the method with `return this`) so you can chain calls on that object (hence, make it "fluent").

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

In your case, its not a matter of method chaining.
Calling `http.createServer` returns a new object different than http, which you can call listen on.

Answer (score 0):

This is because **createServer** returns a new instance of **http.Server**.

```
Class: http.Server
```

This class inherits from **net.Server** and has the Event **'listening'**.
[More information](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server)